# How to allow users from only some specific tenants to be able to login to my app using Azure AD

Tags: c#, angularjs, visual-studio, azure, active-directory

I am building an SPA using AngularJs and using Azure AD for authentication purpose. **My app is a multi-tenanted.**

But, I can see that Azure AD is allowing users from any Tenant of any Active Directory to login to my app.

They are just presented with a consent screen (after successful login) where they are asked whether they are comfortable with providing access to their information from the app, **and if they clicked yes**, then they are freely redirected to my app's home page (if they have callback url to my app).

I tried modifying **Manifest** file of my app and adding some **Tenants** to the `knownClientApplications` property to allow users from only that *Tenant* but for no avail.

The AngularJs config code being:

```
adalProvider.init(
 {
     instance: AZURE_AD_INSTANCE,
     tenant: 'common',
     clientId: AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID,
     extraQueryParameter: 'nux=1',
     //cacheLocation: 'localStorage', // enable this for IE, as sessionStorage does not work for localhost.
 }, $httpProvider);
```

where, AZURE_AD_INSTANCE and AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID are login url and app's client id respectively.

What could I do to allow users from only specific tenants and disallow others?

Comment: Please feel free to let me know whether the post is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To only enable the specific tenants for the multi-tenant application, we need to verify the tenant ourselves.

Here is the code for your reference(adal-angular.js):

```
  AdalModule.provider('adalAuthenticationService', function () {
      ...
       var updateDataFromCache = function (resource) {
            // only cache lookup here to not interrupt with events
            var token = _adal.getCachedToken(resource);
            // _oauthData.isAuthenticated = token !== null && token.length > 0;
            _oauthData.isAuthenticated = isAuthenticated(token);
            var user = _adal.getCachedUser() || { userName: '' };
            _oauthData.userName = user.userName;
            _oauthData.profile = user.profile;
            _oauthData.loginError = _adal.getLoginError();
        };


        function isAuthenticated(token) {
            console.log(token);
            if (token !== null && token.length > 0) {
                var decodedToken = _adal._extractIdToken(token);
                var tenantIds = ["04e14a2c-0e9b-42f8-8b22-3c4a2f1d8802", "04e14a2c-0e9b-42f8-8b22-3c4a2f1d8801"];
                var validateTenant = tenantIds.indexOf(decodedToken.tid) !== -1;
                return tenantIds.indexOf(decodedToken.tid) !== -1;
            } else
                return false;                
        }
```

And to make users enable to login after they enter the wrong tenant account, we may custom the login method to append `prompt=login`.